# Changing a categorical variable to binary 0 and 1

Tags: r

so what I am trying to do is make the values in the variable default, from the Default dataset, Yes = 1, and No = 0.
I plot it to check if it works, but what I have been doing does not work, as it gives me 1 and 2 for yes and no. Thank you in advance for any help!
Working in RStudio.r

```
library(ISLR)
Default
Default$default=as.numeric(Default$default, levels=c("Yes","No"),labels=c(1,0))
model= lm(default~balance, data=Default)
with(Default,plot(balance,default))
```

Comment: Usually, I'd use `dplyr` and the `mutate` function to revalue. `df` %>% mutate(levels = ifelse("Yes", 1, 0)` Hope it helps

Comment: You're running a standard linear regression on a binary outcome, which doesn't always work well because the predicted values aren't constrained between 0 and 1. If you use something like `glm`, it should be set up to deal with categorical outcomes by default, so you may not need to transform the variable.

Comment: `Error in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) : variable 1 has no levels` i am given the following error

Comment: Yes, sorry Marius, that is what we were taught to do, however this question asks us to do it using linear regression. The next question is logistic regression.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after

```
Default$default <- ifelse(Default$default == "Yes",1,0)
model= lm(default~balance, data=Default)
with(Default,plot(balance,default))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Default$default <- as.numeric(Default$default == "Yes")
```

Comment: It appears through the plot that this just made everything a "Yes". Thank you though.

Comment: @JoseJimenez Should be `"Yes"`, not `"yes"`, try it now

Comment: yeah, that's what i originally put